# Renaming or reorder vertex groups of a mesh to match the names of a second mesh

Tags: python, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have two meshes which share similar vertex groups (positions), but they have different names and order. I want to reorder or rename the vertex groups from the first mesh to match the second one.

The only thing that came to my mind is to visually compare each vertex group in weight view to find its match in the second mesh and then rename it. Too tedious to do it for almost 200 vertex groups.

Is there any more efficient way to do this task?

Comment: scripting is always your friend for tedious work. There is a scripting for artists course on the Blender Foundation Youtube Channel if you are interrested.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. The problem is that this process requires a visual inspection of each vertex group. But I don't know if there is a tool in blender to automatic identify similar vertex groups and then rename according to the second mesh.

Comment: You can code an euclidian distance function (also called L2 Distance) to compare the vertex groups